# powershell pmc: can't install package to specific project with wildcard

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I am trying to install a package with nuget package manager console like so:

```
install-package packageName -version 6.2.2 -ProjectName (Get-Project -all | where {$_.ProjectName -like "*.project.frontend"})
```

note the wildcard.

I have two projects, these are:

- [customerName].project.frontend
- [customerName].project.backend

Because the cutomerName is different each time, I need to use a wildcard for it.

The problem is that when I try to run the command, I get this error:

```
install-package : Project 'System.__ComObject' is not found.
```

I think I am missing another filter, because to filter that is active right now returns the whole project instead of just the projectname. But I am not sure.

So the question is:

How do i install a package for a specific project that has a wildcard?

Comment: Does expanding the ProjectName with `Select-Object` work? e.g. `Get-Project -all | where {$_.ProjectName -like "*.project.frontend"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProjectName`

Comment: This works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you hypothesized in your question, you are passing the entire Project object rather than just the `[string]` `PropertyName`.

If you want just a single property of an object you can either use the `Object.Property` notation or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`.

Here is your code using the `Object.Property` notation:

```
Install-Package packageName -Version 6.2.2 -ProjectName ((Get-Project -all | where {$_.ProjectName -like "*.project.frontend"}).ProjectName)
```

Here is your code expanding the property with the `Select-Object` parameter `-ExpandProperty` parameter

```
Install-Package packageName -Version 6.2.2 -ProjectName (Get-Project -all | where {$_.ProjectName -like "*.project.frontend"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProjectName)
```